# Different sensitivity on different mobile devices Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script that moves my character along the X, the moment I move my finger. I need the character not to immediately teleport to the finger, but at a certain speed. I have it set by this script.

```
      if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
            {
                touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                {
                            Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * speed, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
                            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, newPos, Time.deltaTime * smooth);                       
                    
                }
            }
```

How do I fix this? I need to be able to use speed and smooth to set the speed I need, but that it does not affect the screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, newPos, Time.deltaTime * smooth);